# Ionic 3 pause and resume events triggering multiple times in Android

Tags: android, angular, ionic3, ionic-native

I am facing strange issue in ionic 3 pause and resume events, whenever I paused the application, events are calling multiple times(once 2, once 3 etc). 
Here is the code

```
 this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {        
      console.log('****UserdashboardPage PAUSED****');
  });  
  this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {      
      console.log('****UserdashboardPage RESUMED****');
  });
});
```

I have tried by placing the same code in ionViewDidLoad, Constructor, ionViewWillEnter still facing same issue. Please anybody help me to get resolve this. I'm calling one service once the app is resumed but now its calling multiple times.Thanks!!

Comment: @Suraj Rao.. Any luck.. I am calling these event in userdashboard page.. Not in the app.component.js.. Is this might be the problem ??

Comment: is that page lazy loaded? when is it navigated to? I think it may depend on these.. but not sure why it would be called multiple times in constructor

Comment: these events are only calling multiple times.. Constructor and life cycle methods are not calling

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is calling multiple times becuase every time you pause or resume the application it will subscribe to platform.
you need to unsubscribe to platform as following

```
private sub1$:any;
private sub2$:any;

this.platform.ready().then(() => {
  this.sub1$=this.platform.pause.subscribe(() => {        
      console.log('****UserdashboardPage PAUSED****');
  });  
  this.sub2$=this.platform.resume.subscribe(() => {      
      console.log('****UserdashboardPage RESUMED****');
  });
});

ionViewWillUnload() {
    this.sub1$.unsubscribe();
    this.sub2$.unsubscribe();
  }
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I will check it and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```html
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab1',
  templateUrl: 'tab1.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab1.page.scss']
})
export class Tab1Page {


  constructor(private platform:Platform) {}
  resumeListener:Subscription=new Subscription();
ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.resumeListener=this.platform.resume.subscribe(()=>{
    console.log("resume")

  })
}

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.resumeListener.unsubscribe();
  
  }

}
```

it will work even if you have multiple tab
same thing you can do with pause event